# Name for logical predicates which act like homomorphisms from set union to logical conjunction?

Tags: definition, predicate-logic

Is there a name for predicates defined over sets with the property that:

$$P(S\cup Q)\iff P(S)\land P(Q)$$

For example the predicate $P(Q)=``Q\text{ is empty"}$ would be one such predicate because:

$$S\cup Q=\emptyset\iff (S=\emptyset)\land (Q=\emptyset)$$

It looks sort of like the definition for a homomorphism between algebraic structures.

Comment: You mean nonempty?

Comment: If you restrict it to subsets of a universe $U$, you could call it a "morphism of upper semilattices" $P(U) \to \Omega$ where $\Omega$ is the collection of truth values for your logic (e.g. $\{ T, F \}$ for the usual classical logic, or the subobject classifier if working in a topos).

Answer (score 0):

These are *semilattice homomorphisms.* A [semilattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice) is a set with a binary operation that is associative, commutative, and idempotent (i.e., $x \vee x = x$). As in algebra, a semilattice homomorphism is a function that preserves the operation. Examples of semilattices include:

- subsets of a given set, where the operation is union
- subsets of a given set, where the operation is intersection
- propositions, where the operation is conjunction
- propositions, where the operation is disjunction.

So, if you specify what your semilattices are, you get the notion of homomorphism you're looking for.

---

Something to file away for later, since I'm guessing you haven't seen category theory yet: it is very natural, also, to view these maps as functors between certain categories. You're then asking questions related to whether the functors are "left exact" or "right exact."

Comment: Specifically, they are semilattice homomorphisms from the semilattice of sets to the two-element semilattice of truth values.